# How to count datetime type field on Solr search result?

Tags: solr

I want use Solr search and count a result in datetime type field,

If I just use fact_field it will just get 100 rows.

Does anyone have any idea to fix this requirement?

The field like this "created":"2015-09-02T05:57:23Z"

Can I counting this by year or month in Solr?

Comment: Which version of Solr are you using? If we need, could you add new fields and reindex the entire collection?

Comment: I'm using  solr 6.1.0, yes if need i can reindex for this requirement. How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can do this with `facet.range`**

If you want to count document by month of current year and previous year :
Use The Below Param :

```
  "facet.range":"created",
  "q":"*:*",
  "facet.range.gap":"+1MONTH",
  "facet":"true",
  "facet.range.start":"NOW/YEAR-1YEAR",
  "facet.range.end":"NOW"
```

Example :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/test/select?q=*%3A*&facet=true&facet.range=created&facet.range.start=NOW/YEAR-1YEAR&facet.range.end=NOW&facet.range.gap=%2B1MONTH
```

Here

- facet.range

  > The facet.range parameter defines the field for which Solr should create range facets. for your case it's created field.
- facet.range.start

  > The facet.range.start parameter specifies the lower bound of the ranges
- facet.range.end

  > The facet.range.end specifies the upper bound of the ranges
- facet.range.gap

  > The span of each range expressed as a value to be added to the lower bound. For date fields, this should be expressed using the DateMathParser syntax (such as, facet.range.gap=%2B1DAY ... '+1DAY'). for your case it's year or month.

Source :

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-DateFacetingParameters
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates

Comment: how to use specify the date in facet.range.start like  "facet.range.start":"2016-01-05/2016-02-28" can use this? or not?

Comment: What do you mean by `2016-01-05/2016-02-28` ?

Comment: facet.range.start is two values in here; in your example NOW/YEAR-1YEAR ; 1 value : "NOW" ,2 value : "YEAR-1YEAR" , here can i use specify the date range?like 2016-01-05/2016-02-28?

Comment: @ZivHus It's not two value, it's one just one date. I have used NOW/YEAR, A slash is used to indicate rounding. This represents the beginning of the current year.

Comment: oh!! I got it, Thank you~